# Are there any Angular libraries that work perfectly with angular 7.2 and export html template with CSS to a PDF file?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I tried using jsPDF and html2canvas which together take the screenshot of the webpage and generate a PDF file. But I do not want an image to be a PDF file. I want a library that converts the HTML with CSS of dynamic results to a PDF file where the texts are selectable.

Comment: Refer - https://www.codementor.io/amehjoseph/convert-html-css-content-to-a-sleek-multiple-page-pdf-file-using-jspdf-javascript-library-eyyz74hci . Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the PDF creation to be done programmatically? What about just Print to PDF?

If you need a high level of precision, another option, although older and perhaps involving more complexity than you want, is to use [XSL Formatting Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects), or XSL-FO. Given that your HTML is valid XML, you can then use XSL to transform your HTML into Formatting Objects, which in turn is passed into a formatting engine to produce a PDF.

There is a JavaScript project on NPM for doing this named [jsx-xsl-fo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-xsl-fo), though its usage numbers are low. I also doubt you'd be able to do all of this client-side.

Comment: My initial thought was; this is not a job for a clientside project. You want a backend to take care of this.